# Looking for an iPhone SSH app

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, ssh

Is there any FREE real SSH apps for iOS 5. There should not be any jailbreaking.

I wanted something like these:

1. [iPhone SSH clients reviewed: iSSH, pTerm, and TouchTerm](http://www.messagingnews.com/onmessage/ben-gross/iphone-ssh-clients-reviewed-issh-pterm-and-touchterm)
2. [Three SSH terminal apps for iPhone](http://www.macworld.com/appguide/article.html?article=152774)

I want to use an online shell.

Comment: [Panic's Prompt](http://panic.com/prompt/support.html) is worth the $8. Drink less coffee for a week, save your pennies, and then buy the best SSH app on iOS with your saved cash.

Comment: Open up iTunes. Got to the iTunes Store. Search for "SSH". Whatever is listed is all that's there (unless you wish to Jailbreak your device and install apps outside of Apple's ecosystem).

Comment: Putting in a second vote for Panic's Prompt.  It is simply the best and very well worth the money, even if you only use it occasionally.

Comment: The only free one I found at a short glance is zatelnet, but it seems to require an in-app purchase to be really useful. Other than that, I would recommend Panic's Prompt as well.

Comment: Prompt is worth the money. Heard good things about iSSH too.

Comment: There is source available for some versions of iSSH, all old afaik though.

Comment: I subscribe to Prompt. But @cksum hit the nail… it's not hard to see what's there using the App Store :)

Comment: One more vote for Prompt. Worth every cent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Rove Mobile Admin Client](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/rove-mobile-admin-client/id339820302?mt=8) on my iPhone. It's free, there are no annoying in-app ads, and it comes with an SSH client which I use to connect to machines at work while I'm on the road. Works great. It's quite possible to run a remote emacs editor and send all the control characters you need.

Comment: Just to note the SSH functionality is free withe product, but any advanced functionality requires purchase of dedicated admin server software

Comment: Tried them all And... Rove Mobile Admin is the Best.

Answer (score 9):

## [Prompt](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prompt/id421507115?mt=8) for iOS

Prompt allows you to remotely [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into another machine. Without jailbreaking, there is no way to use Terminal to access your file system. However, I've found that if you do jailbreak your phone and want to use Prompt as a Terminal, you can set it to SSH to server `127.0.0.1` and authenticate with the [standard iPhone root credentials](http://www.mydigitallife.info/apple-iphone-root-password-and-mobile-user-password/).

## [Remoter: Remote Desktop (VNC)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remoter-remote-desktop-vnc/id369626098?mt=8) for iOS

This app does basically the same thing just a little differently. By default it allows a VNC connection for screen sharing, but it has different add ons that you can purchase that allow SSH, [Telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), and [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).

Comment: Prompt is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

vSSH for [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/vssh/id527244258?mt=8) and [iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/vssh-hd/id530136764?mt=8). There is a free lite version. Ad is quite annoying, but functionality and usability are fantastic.

There is also OS X version and it's possible to share connections between all these apps via iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

While I would recommend Prompt, there is an OK SSH client called [zaTelnet](http://www.zatelnet.com/iphoneproducts.html). It is free, but I think feature limited (as in, a limited number of characters per session, etc).

[App Store link for zaTelnet](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/zatelnet/id407082048?mt=8).